# calling two js functions one after another using one button

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code, not working please help I want to call two js functions using one submit button.I have tried the below code.But it gives error.

```js
function scrollWin() {

    // First time click
    if (e.name != 'Click') {
        e.name = "Click";

        function scrollWin() {
            window.scrollBy(0, 85);
        }
    }

    // When click it again..
    else if (e.name == 'Click') {
        e.name = "Unclick";

        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<h2> Second Click </h2>";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="scrollWin(); this.style.visibility= 'hidden'; 
myFunction()" value="Click Me" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: And what is the error?  It's not obvious from this code what you're trying to accomplish.  And naming two different functions the same thing is just asking for confusion.  If you want to call two functions, then you just call each function one after the other.  `functionOne(); functionTwo();`  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define one function which handles this action. It is probably best to store a variable where you can save the state of the clicking. Here is an example:

```js
var clickCount = 0;

function scrollWin(button) {
    // first click
    if (clickCount === 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0, 85);
    }
    // second or more click
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<h2> Second Click </h2>";
        button.style.display = 'none';
    }
    clickCount++;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="scrollWin(this)" value="Click Me" />

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @AmitTiwari I've adapted it. I'm now passing the button as an argument and set the style property on a second click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the fundamentals right. A function call will have its own scope and once the scope of a function ends, the variables are destroyed. I think you want to capture a second click for the element.

Don't try declaring a global variable for the same but try to set the elements property on first click which you can access on the second click. read that property on click and then manipulate.

I would suggest you to call the click event as

```
onclick="click123(this);"
```

and use this to set the property using `setAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

I think this accomplishes what you described. You need to pass in the event of the button click and read the button text, but `e.name` probably wont work you'll need to use `innerHTML` or `textContent`. Then you can either perform the operations or call the functions you wish to execute depending on the button text which changes after the 2nd click.

```js
         function scrollWin(e) {

            //First time click
            if(e.textContent != 'Click'){
                e.textContent = "Click";
                window.scrollBy(0, 85);
            }

            else if(e.textContent == 'Click'){
                e.textContent = "Unclick";
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<h2> Second Click </h2>";
            }//end else
        }//end function
```

```html
<button onclick="scrollWin(this)">Click</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you want to perform two operation on same button but in two different condition, if you want to perform keep state and perform action according to that then. Like:

```
    function scrollWin(e) {
    var btn = e.target;

    var state = btn.dataset.myattr;

    if( state == 'state1'){
        btn.dataset.myattr = 'state2';
        e.name = "Click";
        window.scrollBy(0, 85);
    }else if (state == 'state2'){
        btn.dataset.myattr = 'state1';
        e.name = "Unclick";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<h2> Second Click </h2>";
    }
}
```

If you want to change the name attribute to something else you can do that and you don't have to change the JS code for that.

Comment: Yes, in the else block, add the code to hide the element. using style attribute, like: btn.style.display = 'none'; Request you to please mark it as answer and give up vote . Thanks

Comment: if you are referring my answer, remember to give 'state1' as the default state to button. You can give that using data-myattr='state1' in the html to the button tag.

Comment: Yes you can do here also, in the else block just write the code to hide it  btn.style.display = 'none'; And if my answer is not correct atleast give me upvote. Thanks